# Detecting shapes that are not one connected component in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, contour

The code should detect letters and numbers with OpenCV. The problem is that it can't detect letters with two parts, for example i, j, or the arabic letters ب،ت،ث،ج،خ،ض etc.

This is my code:

```
image = cv2.imread('output.png')

height, width, depth = image.shape

# resizing the image to find spaces better
image = cv2.resize(image, dsize=(width * 5, height * 4), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
# grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# binary
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# dilation
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

# adding GaussianBlur
gsblur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_dilation, (5, 5), 0)

# find contours
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(gsblur.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

m = list()
# sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
pchl = list()
dp = image.copy()
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    cv2.rectangle(dp, (x - 10, y - 10), (x + w + 10, y + h + 10), (90, 0, 255), 9)
```

What would I need to change to detect shapes with multiple parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursive inline optical character recognition is not an easy task, not really from the perspective of individual character recognition but because of proper segmentation in individual characters.

A popular approach in this domain is to identify each conex item, isolate them, and build some kind of association algorithm. Basicly you will have a bunch of characters parts, **some are complete** characters **some are not**. For these incomplete items (that cannot be classified as a character on their own) check the neighborhood of that item  in order to build a char with the items around it (may they be left or right, or even a bit upper or lower). The feedback of a classifier is crucial for the segmentation task.

You will find this approach in the literature under the name of: **Implicit over segmentation** or **Recognition-based segmentation**. More details in [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2698/e7bf14e1a57b1cc314b8216125d1631a5fff.pdf) and [this](https://research-repository.griffith.edu.au/handle/10072/23529) papers, and for arabic characters more in [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/eeeb/fc3aef9006d412c3d1080410b6e04d5a6bb6.pdf) article.